# 19.10: Brightness keys on Xubuntu don't change brightness but switch between mute/unmute instead

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, brightness

I have been using Xubuntu as single boot on my laptop for about one year and everything worked great, the keys on the keyboard did what they were meant to do.

Then i needed to install Windows 10 for some program in college (Atmel Studio) which wasn't supported on linux.

I did that.

It was kinda hard to install windows after linux without wiping linux out (like creating a partition and installing windows there and make the laptop boot on grub per default so that u can choose the os u want to boot into)

anyways after a while i noticed the brightness keys on my HP Probook which are under f3 and f4 do not change the brightness any more in xubuntu but instead whenever i press them it just mutes/unmutes the microphone.
And when i boot in windows the keys do actually change the brightness.

It really bothers to have to go to settings and change brightness each time when the room lighting changes as it used to be so much more convenient just using the keyboard.

I hope some of you guys have an idea of what the problem might be and maybe help me out.

---

Update

It is Xubuntu actually, because it has an XFCE Desktop.

```
andi@andilicious:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Comment: To start with, which release number of Xubuntu is used?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Hello @K7AAY i added the release. i think this is what you wanted. Please let me know if you need anything else, and also how to get it.

Comment: @K7AAY Could it be that i updated to 19.10? Bc i used to have 18.smth. That might be another reason why the issue might have occured. It happend around the same time as installing Windows so i can't really tell. Anyways i hope this somehow helps to fix the issue.